# A fast way to count non-empty regions

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I am writing some code that chooses `n` random hyperplanes in 5 dimensions that go through the origin. It then samples `no_points` points uniformly at random on the unit sphere and counts how many of the regions created by the hyperplanes have at least one point in them.  This is relatively simple to do using the following Python code.

```
import numpy as np

def points_on_sphere(dim, N, norm=np.random.normal):
    """
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points
    """
    normal_deviates = norm(size=(N, dim))
    radius = np.sqrt((normal_deviates ** 2).sum(axis=0))
    points = normal_deviates / radius
    return points

n = 100
d = 5
hpoints = points_on_sphere(n, d).T
for no_points in xrange(0, 10000000,100000):
    test_points = points_on_sphere(no_points,d).T 
    #The next two lines count how many of the test_points are in different regions created by the hyperplanes
    signs = np.sign(np.inner(test_points, hpoints))
    print no_points, len(set(map(tuple,signs)))
```

Unfortunately, my naive method of counting how many of the points are in different regions is slow. Overall the method takes `O(no_points * n * d)` time and in practice it is too slow and too RAM hungry once `no_points` reaches about `1000000`. In particular it reaches 4GB of RAM at `no_points = 900,000` .

Can this be done more efficiently so that `no_points` can get all the way to 10,000,000 (actually it would be great if it could go to 10 times that) fairly quickly and using less than 4GB of RAM?

Comment: I haven't tried to follow the logic for generating the points, but can't you just generate them one at a time, counting them as you go, instead of storing them all in a list?  They are, after all, *independent* samples -- right?

Comment: @j_random_hacker The problem is to count one point per region. So if you create the points one at a time you still need to check all the previous points to make sure this new point is not in the same region as any of them.  You are right I think that maybe you can use less space with this approach.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's a very good point.. but I am not sure how to do that efficiently myself.  For example, I don't know to represent a region by a number or how to look up which region a point is in. Also, the number of regions in the example code I have given is 7,852,352 so not that different from the maximum number of points .

Comment: I think the only data structure you need is an O(m) array of booleans, where m is the number of regions.  Generate each random point in succession, find the region it belongs to, and set that element of the array to TRUE.

Comment: How large is n? If you count regions naively, the number could be 2 ** n (actually, many regions could be empty, but this would require additional computations).

Comment: Oh, now I see. It is defined as 100. So having an array of regions can't be done naively.

Comment: @matiasg The number of regions is 7,852,352 .

Comment: `O(n_points * n * d)` does not seem that large. To save RAM, you can store the signs in a bit vector for each point so it takes only 100 bits per point. So I would say the problem is with python, not the algorithm itself. Do you consider using another language an option?

Comment: @user2040251 O(n_points * n * d) is just a bit too large if no_points > 10,000,000 I think. 10,000,000 * 100 * 5 = 5,000,000,000 so it seems tricky if no_points is much larger than that.  I don't really mind which language it is in I am just not very good at any others. Do you know how to get the signs into a bit vector in python?

Comment: @user2179021 I don't know how to do in python. What running do you want  to achieve(several seconds, minutes)?

Comment: @user2040251 A few minutes for the larger case (no_points is 100 million) would be fine.

Comment: @user2179021 for 10^8 points, it takes about 5 * 10^10 operations and around 10^10 bits of RAM(it is less then 4 GB). It is possible to make it run in several minutes using efficient C or C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing how each test point classifies with respect to each hyperplane is a lot of data. I would suggest an implicit radix sort on the point labels, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np


d = 5
n = 100
N = 100000
is_boundary = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
tpoints = np.random.normal(size=(N, d))
tperm = np.arange(N)
for i in range(n):
    hpoint = np.random.normal(size=d)
    region = np.cumsum(is_boundary) * 2 + (np.inner(hpoint, tpoints) < 0.0)[tperm]
    region_order = np.argsort(region)
    is_boundary[1:] = np.diff(region[region_order])
    tperm = tperm[region_order]
print(np.sum(is_boundary))
```

This code keeps a permutation of test points (`tperm`) such that all points in the same region are consecutive. `boundary` indicates whether each point is in a different region from the previous in permutation order. For each successive hyperplane, we partition each of the existing regions and effectively discard the empty regions to avoid storage for 2^100 of them.

Actually, since you have so many points and so few hyperplanes, it makes more sense not to store the points. The following code packs the region signature into two doubles using binary encoding.

```
import numpy as np


d = 5
hpoints = np.random.normal(size=(100, d))
bits = np.zeros((2, 100))
bits[0, :50] = 2.0 ** np.arange(50)
bits[1, 50:] = 2.0 ** np.arange(50)
N = 100000
uniques = set()
for i in xrange(0, N, 1000):
    tpoints = np.random.normal(size=(1000, d))
    signatures = np.inner(np.inner(tpoints, hpoints) < 0.0, bits)
    uniques.update(map(tuple, signatures))
print(len(uniques))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you mind adding a couple of lines of non-numpy/Python explanation for your method for those of us who are better at algorithms than numpy/Python?